# Mongo DB converts '_' into a number

Tags: mongodb, csv, import

while importing the CSV file in mongodb we have a value like `6910001_1001`. When we import the CSV file it convert `6910001_1001` into `69100011001.0`

How can I restrict auto datatype selection in Mongodb?

Comment: Which tool do you use for import?

Comment: We are using Batch command for import

Comment: There is no Batch command do connect to a MongoDB. Again, which tool do you use?